# Select em duas tabelas. Como retornar uma única lista?

Tags: java, sql

Tenho uma tabela Processos, com dados básicos e outra ProcessosDestaque, com dados mais específicos. Preciso fazer um select que chame algumas colunas dos dados básicos e outras dos dados específicos. Tentei fazer uma lista, mas só consigo chamar os dados de apenas uma tabela.

Na primeira tabela Processos, tenho as seguintes colunas: `codGeral,classeProc, numProc, autorProc, ResumoProc`.

A tabela ProcessosDestaque possui as seguintes colunas: `codDest, codGeral(chave estrangeira), ementaProc, dispProc`.

O método listarDest está assim:

```
public List listarDest()
{
List lst= new ArrayList<>();

List lstDest = newArrayList<>();
try
{
stmt = con.prepareStatement(“SELECT codigoGeral.Processos, classe.Processos, numProc.Processos, autor.Processos, codDest.ProcessosDestaques, ementaProc.ProcessosDestaque FROM ProcessosDestaque JOIN Processos ON ProcessosDestaque.codGeral = Processos.codGeral”);

rs = stmt.executeQuery();

while(rs.next())

{

ProcDestaques procdestaques = new ProcDestaques();

Proc proc = new Proc();

procdestaques.setCodDest(rs.getInt(1));

procdestaques.setCodGeral(rs.getInt(2));

proc.setClasse(rs.getString(3));

proc. setNumProc(rs.getString(4));

proc.setAutor(rs.getString(5));

procdestaques.setEmentaProc(rs.getString(6));

lstDest.add(procdestaques);

lst.add(proc);

}

stmt.execute();

rs.close();

con.close();

}

catch (SQLException e)

{

throw new RuntimeException(e);

}

return lstDest;

}
```

Alguém tem ideia de como fazer para o select retornar os dados das duas tabelas?

Comment: Amigo vi na sua sql que vc esta colocando o nome do campo e depois o nome da tabela o correto é o nome da tabela de depois a do campo. Tenta executa assim :"SELECT Processos.codigoGeral, Processos.classe, Processos.numProc, Processos.autor, ProcessosDestaques.codDest, ProcessosDestaque.ementaProc FROM ProcessosDestaque JOIN Processos ON ProcessosDestaque.codGeral = Processos.codGeral"

Comment: Depende como você quer o resultado. Pode usar JOINS, ou UNION ALL. No seu caso que tem ligação entre elas, o ideal seria o JOIN como fez. Para gerar a tabela, para facilitar, gere um array, e depois irá tratar com 1 loop dentro de outro.

Answer (score -1):

Amigo você pode usar `query` nativa, e a `query` seria assim mais ou menos:

```
SELECT processo.codGeral, processo.classe, processo.numProc, processo.autor, detalhe.codDest,  processo.numProc FROM Processos processo, ProcessosDestaque detalhe WHERE processo.codGeral = detalhe.codGeral
```

Espero ter ajudado.